# How can get full name from INFO TABLES at Informix DB

Tags: sql, informix

I'm not very good with cli and I need help getting the full names of restricted tables +
, for example: aardialprefixmatr+

```
> info tables;

Table name

aardialprefixmatr+ aarneighborhood    activationcode     activationcodetbr 
advanceddevicecon+ agentnumplandynam+ alarmconfig        alarmmonitorcapab+
alarmusertext      alternatenumber    analogaccess       analogaccessport  
apdiscoveryschedu+ apdiscoveryserver  applicationdialru+ applicationuser
```

It would be nice to display them in one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest technique is to run the query directly instead of using `INFO TABLES`:

```
SELECT tabname FROM "informix".systables WHERE tabid >= 100;
```

The system catalog tables have numbers less than 100.  You could specify `AND tabtype = 'T'` if you want table names only rather than including views and synonyms too.  You can specify the order that the rows should appear in (`ORDER BY tabname` or `ORDER BY tabid` or `ORDER BY owner, tabname`, etc).  That will show the data with the column name (`tabname`) and the value (the table name):

```
tabname  dual

tabname  elements

tabname  compound

tabname  compound_component

tabname  isotopes

tabname  named_isotopes

tabname  megalopolis_created_by_ozymandias_in_times_uncertain_but_distant_and_n
         ot_called_atlantis
```